# PHP - files/folders manipulation issue while online

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-upload, directory, media

I made a **back-office**, with a page to create a new "*album*" (containing photos) which create folders, files, moves uploaded photos.

**Everything works on local**, I made multiple tests before setting my work online.
Now I wanted to test it on the host:
I send the files and fill the whole form.
I submit and wait for file transfer. The page should refresh after transfer with succeeding messages, and *folders*, *files* and *DB elements* should be created but **the page just refresh as if nothing was sent**. And nothing has been created.

I set by `.htaccess` my modified `php.ini` path for the values:

- `max_file_uploads=500`
- `upload_max_filesize=50M`
- `post_max_size=2500M`
- `memory_limit=2500M`
- `max_input_time=3600`

My .htaccess contains :

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/clanglois/public_html
```

I used the functions `mkdir()` with permission `0755`.
The *DB* keeps empty for the *tables* the script should work with, but I know the **DB connexion works** (I added a new user, it automatically send an email. That works).

Is there additionnal authorisations to set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have not writing right on the server. Try to add it. You need this right in order to your script be able to write on the disk.

```
chmod 755 yourFolder/
```

This above line set rights for yourFolder, not recursively. Owner will can read-write-execute, others will can read-execute only. Adapt right at your own need. If you want this to be recursive, use `-R` option.

To check rights on your system, use `ls -l`

See [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

Comment: I guess I can use the `chmod()` function with PHP ?
How can I try the command lines you wrote ?

Comment: I don't have SSH access on my host

Comment: You can use [chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) with PHP indeed, if it has the right to update rights. Also, Filezilla allows via FTP to manage chmod. Try with PHP to create a folder with right 777 and move your photos into it. If it works, this is because of rights on the other folder. Obviously, never use a 777 right in production.

Comment: Well, I finally saw the permissions on all my files and folders (I didn't realize I could see that in the cPanel). The folders are already set to 755...
But thanks anyway it helps understanding !

Comment: So is your user owner of folder ? With this configuration, only the owner can write.

Comment: Ouch maybe I missed something there..
How can be set the user ?

Comment: The user (perhaps `www-data`) has to be owner of folder to be able to write.

Comment: Hi again ! I searched and I am the right user. I think the problem is more specific. I accept your answer because it helped a lot. Thanks man !